# Write text between two text strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

Lets say I have this data in a file (externalfile.txt)

```
#1#First#/1#
#2#Something#/2#

#end#
```

I want to write text between `#/2#` and `#end#`, How to do this?

Comment: I realise this might be due to a language barrier, but the words please and thank you might get you further.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's the proper way but you may take a look

```
$newval='new text';
$file_contents = file_get_contents('externalfile.txt');
file_put_contents('externalfile.txt', preg_replace("/#\/2#/", "#/2#\n$newval\n", $file_contents));
```

It works, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused :-)

Answer (score 1):

This PHP code inserts a new text right before the last occurence of the `#end#` string:

```php
$str = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$splitted = explode('#end#',$str);
$pos = count($splitted)-2;
$splitted[$pos] .= 'new text';
$str = implode('#end#',$splitted);
echo $str;
```